# Want to set 18 years back date when i click on date field in IOS device(IPhone6 &5)

Tags: html

I am facing issue in iOS device when I try to set the date back 18 years when I click on a date field. In fraction of seconds it gets changed to the current day. Here is my code. On Android this functionality is working fine.

**HTML:**

```
<input id="datePicker" type="date" />
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready( function() {    
    var now = new Date(); 
    var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var yyyy = now.getFullYear()-18;
    var day18yb = yyyy+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;
    $('#datePicker').val(''); // By default it should be empty so setting empty value    
    $('#datePicker').click(function(){ //When i click on date it should be 18 years back date
        $('#datePicker').val(day18yb);
    });
});
```